# What do these Array console.logs mean?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If I expand the Arrays, they all look the same on the inside. Why then is the first one labeled as [Array[4]] and the last one as [Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]]?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the little `i` icon explains, expand an object shows its *present* value.

This would happen if you log the same array instance multiple times, and add items between logs.

It prints the value of the array (the collapsed line) immediately, so it shows the original value of the array.
When you expand it, it expands the current state of the object, including later additions.

Comment: For sure, just wanted to make sure there weren't repeats, or something strange going on. Thanks!